# How do you display an image from fire storage to UIImageView on user profile View Controller?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, firebase-storage

I have coded this much and was able to get the `UIImagePickerController` setup that when user selects photo that it automatically uploads it to their uid assigned them from `Firestore` database, however when I go to another viewController and then switch back to the profile viewController the image has reset and I can go through the process again of picking an image of which it will upload to fire storage but will not remain in the `UIImageView` upon returning to the profile page.

Any help on how to get the image to stay or how to fetch and display it in the UIImageView every time a user goes to their user profile page?  Thanks

here is the code on how I allow the user to pick and how it uploads to fire storage.

```
extension ProfileViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let imageSelected = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage
        {
            image = imageSelected
            profileimage.image = imageSelected
            
        } else if let imageOriginal = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            image = imageOriginal
            profileimage.image = imageOriginal
        }
        guard let imageSelected = image?.pngData() else {
            return
        }
        
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            storage.child("images/"+Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid+"+.png").putData(imageSelected, metadata: nil, completion: { _, error in
            })
            
            func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
                picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            
        }
        
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my own question so I figured I would post the solution.  The `UIImagePickerController` code as listed in the question was correct and I am able to use this with one change to make the image load a lot faster.  In place of the `imageSelected = image?.pngData()` I replaced that with this...

```
guard let imageSelected = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else { return }
```

and I also created a function to download the image and placing it inside of the `UIImageView` each time a user revisits the profile page and if they choose they can simply click on the image and upload a new profile pic and the download images function keeps it set.  Here is the function I used to accomplish this...

```
private func downloadimages() {
    let reference = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "\("images/"+Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid+"+.jpg")")
    reference.downloadURL { (URL, error) in
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: URL!)
        let image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
        self.profileimage.image = image
    }
}
```

I simply called this function in the

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

and presto, works perfect!